# How to add a string to resource values programmatically?

Tags: android

To get a string from the resourses in android using java i use

```
  Resources res=this.getResources();
    String ch=res.getString(R.string.naeme);
```

but now i want to add a string to strings.xml using java code , how to do that ?

Comment: You can't really change the values in resources programmatically, can you describe what are you trying to achieve so that I can help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

strings.xml is a constants file and it can't be modified at run time. Hence you can't write any string to strings.xml file

Use shared preference to store any string if needed